# More app.use match the same route. How to avoid multiple calls of the middleware inside app.use()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning Node.
I'm sending data from a form (with ajax) to a server Node on the route `/login2`
I would know what does it happens if I have two `app.use` call like that

```
 app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use("/login2", [express.urlencoded({ extended: false }),moduleValidation]);
```

For my `/login2` the middleware `express.urlencoded` is called twice?
And how could I avoid that double call?

Comment: Why are you adding `urlencoded` twice with the same settings? It seems like the second call to `app.use` should be just `app.use("/login2", moduleValidation);`...?

Comment: With your suggest for the route `/login2` are called in order first the middleware `express.urlencoded` and later `moduleValidation` ? I think it's so because my first app.use already match `/login2` route too. Is it right?

Comment: You'll want to test it, but yes, middleware is called in order of registration.